# Projection onto the set of radiality contraints

Tags: graph-theory, trees, network

Let $G$ be a graph of $n$ arcs and let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to compute the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto the set of radial graphs with $k$ roots contained in $G$ (or a forest with $k$ root) i.e. $$\Pi \left( x\right) =\underset{y\in S}{\arg \min }\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert
^{2},$$
where $S$ is the underlying set.

My question is: how is this projection linked to the minimal spanning trees?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.